# Drywall anchor above or below previous anchor

Tags: drywall-anchor

I accidentally put in a (fairly large) concrete anchor instead of the proper drywall anchor. As I’m trying to correct this, I’ve left the concrete anchor in place assuming this is better than removing it and was wondering if I can place the correct drywall anchor a few inches above or below? I’m hanging a 15 lb mirror that only has one hanging hole.

Thanks!

Comment: BTW, if you decide to remove the concrete anchor for the sake of appearance, patching a hole of a cm or two diameter in drywall is relatively easy for a DIY amateur. The only difficulty might be matching paint color, if it's not white. Some URLS: https://www.homedepot.com/c/ah/how-to-patch-drywall/9ba683603be9fa5395fab90db38ddbf and https://www.lowes.com/n/how-to/patch-and-repair-drywall

Comment: Please take the [tour]. Crip659's comment was inappropriate and should've been an answer below. "OMG" comments are discouraged.

Comment: Please consider [merging your unregistered and registered accounts](/help/merging-accounts), which will allow you to [edit](/help/privileges/create-posts), [comment on](/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts and most importantly [accept an answer](/help/someone-answers) on your question. Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1):

If the old hole is a few inches away, then it makes no difference structurally if you put the new hole above or below or to the side. The only way that the old hole could cause problems is if you put the new one *right above* it (like, less than an inch).

But if the hanger on your mirror is right at the top of the mirror, then you probably want to put the new hole above the old hole, in order to hide the old hole.

Consider using a picture hook instead of a drywall anchor. They tend to cause less damage to the wall. Get one that's rated for *more* than the weight of the mirror, which shouldn't be difficult.

[image]